# java byte operation doubt

Tags: java, byte, arrays, hex

```
public final byte[] getParam(String commandName,String memLocation,String dataId){
    byte[] result = new byte[9];
    //"GET_PARAM", "RAM","WATER_OUTLET_TEMP"
    result[0] = START_FRAME.getBytes()[0]; // {
    result[1] = START_FRAME.getBytes()[0]; // {
    result[2] = Integer.toHexString(commandMap.get(commandName)).getBytes()[0]; // 0xD2
    result[3] = Integer.toHexString(dataIdMap.get(dataId)).getBytes()[0];  // 0x1
    result[4] = Integer.toHexString(locationMap.get(memLocation)).getBytes()[0]; //0x00
    result[5] = Integer.toHexString(commandMap.get(commandName) + dataIdMap.get(dataId) + locationMap.get(memLocation)).getBytes()[0];
    result[6] = END_FRAME.getBytes()[0]; // }
    result[7] = END_FRAME.getBytes()[0]; // }
    result[8] = END_OF_LINE.getBytes()[0]; // \r
    return result;
}
```

For this function certain cases like `result[2]` where `0xD2` is stored and the bytes value come as `[100,23]`...the values dont come out as expected then...only the first half is taken... how do i handle such cases?? for `result[0]` where it is just `[123]`, its fine...

Comment: I sugegst you try this in a debugger and see what it is really doing.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To turn a String "0xD0" in to a byte I suggest you use Integer.decode(String).byteValue() which can handle Java style `0` and `0x` numbers/

I suggest you try something like

```
byte[] result = { 
     '{',
     '{', 
     commandMap.get(commandName), 
     dataIdMap.get(dataId), 
     locationMap.get(memLocation), 
     (byte) (commandMap.get(commandName) + dataIdMap.get(dataId) + locationMap.get(memLocation)), 
     '}', 
     '}', 
     '\r' };
return result;
```

I would change commandMap etc. to be of type Map<String, Byte>

EDIT: Here is a longer example

```
String commandName = "";
String dataId = "";
String memLocation= "";
Map<String, Byte> commandMap = new LinkedHashMap<String, Byte>();
commandMap.put(commandName, Integer.decode("0xD2").byteValue());
Map<String, Byte> dataIdMap = new LinkedHashMap<String, Byte>();
dataIdMap.put(dataId, Integer.decode("0x1").byteValue());
Map<String, Byte> locationMap = new LinkedHashMap<String, Byte>();
locationMap.put(memLocation, Integer.decode("0x00").byteValue());

byte[] result = { '{', '{', commandMap.get(commandName), dataIdMap.get(dataId), locationMap.get(memLocation), (byte) (commandMap.get(commandName) + dataIdMap.get(dataId) + locationMap.get(memLocation)), '}', '}', '\r' };

System.out.println(Arrays.toString(result));
```

prints

```
[123, 123, -46, 1, 0, -45, 125, 125, 13]
```

Comment: You may as well make the map return the type you need. ;)

Comment: You might like to try the longer example.

Comment: hey... thnks a lot...sorry if i am wrong.. after all this computation..if i print result as String.. i am supposed to get the message in string like this right {{D210..}} right...but when i do a System.out.println(new String(result)); i get -> {{Ò }}.. is this a fundamental understanding mistake that i have got ??

Comment: You should get the output I suggested for based code you provided.  If you want `{{D210}}` that means you want to use two bytes (being 'D' and '2') for the command and one for the dataId '1' and location '0'. Is that correct?

Comment: yes basically these values 0xD2 0x00 0x1 etc have to retrieved again..these are sent from client to server in sockets..so in server these have to be retrieved again

Comment: That is not the same thing at all. You have a clear idea of what each byte should be as there are so many ways you can do this.  You have a byte in your code which is like a checksum, but in your example you don't have it.  what do you expect this sum of bytes to do?

Comment: the sum of bytes is just to verify that no data loss has happened...Anyway.. i have solved the problem...i was doing an unwanted conversion to hexString and using getBytes which was a blunter again..... i have stored the hex values directly in the form of bytes...now its fine.. thanks Peter..

Comment: commandMap.put("REQUEST_SET_DISPLAY", (byte)0xD0); stored data like this and then stored in the form of bytes                            result[2] = UARTConstants.commandMap.get(commandName); // 0xD2 ...etc

Answer (score 3):

Do you know what `String.getBytes()` even does? To be honest, this code looks like you don't know or you expect it to do something that it doesn't.

It converts the `String` object to a `byte[]` in the platform default encoding. Taking the `byte` at position `0` only tells you how the first character is represented in the platform default encoding (if it is a singly-byte encoding, otherwise it tells you even less).

What do you want to achieve? You also use `Integer.toHexString()`. Could you give us an example what *exactly* you want the result to be when doing `Integer.toHexString(100).getBytes()[0]`?

Comment: ok... guess my understanding is wrong then... i am very new to this byte and hexa calculations... i am actually supposed to send some hexa values in bytes.. for instance 0xD2 is one of the values that has to be sent in bytes...can u tell me where i have gone wrong?

Comment: @Arun: it depends: in what data type do you have the `0xD2`? Or is it a constant value?

Comment: Integer... its a constant value... and i will have to send data like this {{ 0xD1 0Xd2 0x00 0xD1+0Xd2+0x00 }} over socketconnection...as bytes in hexadecimal value..

Comment: @Arun: there is no "bytes in hexadecimal value". All bytes in our computers and networks are in binary. Hexadecimal is a human-readable format used to present data to humans.

Comment: oke.guess i told it wrong... i meant that i have to send hexadecimal values in the form of bytes... is that correct ?